# React setState won't update the view of my table

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, react-bootstrap-table

I am having hard time changing the view of the Bootstrap table, even though the state is being updated.

I did some research and found that *this.setState* is async, so I made sure to check and change the state in the callback function; however, the state is changed even at the callback function. I am confused if this is still a *this.setState* problem.

```
export class EduInfo extends React.Component {

constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        education: this.props.incomingClass.degreeEdu
    };
    
    this.updateEdu = this.updateEdu.bind(this);
}

updateEdu = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let newEdu = {...this.props.incomingClass};
    BackEndRestService.updateEdu(newEdu).then(data => {
        this.setState({
            education: data.degreeEdu,
        }, () => console.log(data));
    }).catch(e => {
    console.log(e);
    });
}

render(){
    return(
        <BootstrapTable
        hover
        condensed={true}
        bootstrap4={true}
        keyField={'id'}
        data={this.state.education}
        columns={this.columns}
        />
    );

}
```

}

Once the state is updated, it should be re-rendering and updating the *'data={this.state.education}'* in the Bootstrap table. However, the table view is not changing.

Comment: did you verify that you're getting the data you expect from the backend?

Comment: as a side note, you shouldn't be making requests in the components lifecycle. if a request is hanging and the user navigates away then setState on an unmounted component will raise an exception.

Comment: @JohnRuddell. Yes, I am seeing the data being received in the debugger mode. Should I put the request in somewhere else like ComponentDidMount()? And including the setState as well?

Comment: you should have a function that is in a different file (not a component), that makes the request. Use a state management framework like `redux` for example to then send that data to your global store.

Answer (score 0):

At your return function have something like:

```
   return(
    { (this.state.readyToShow)?
       <div>
              <BootStrapTable ... 
              />
       </div>
        : ''
    } );
```

After the state of ReadyToShow is set you should be able to see the Bootstrap table with the info.
And change the state of the state readyToShow (possibly using a callback) only at the end of the response of the request you sent for the data. The problem I see is that your data might not be arriving before react renders. This situation happened to me a lot of times. For example, if using Axios to get data:

```
val axios4data = axios.get(*some link to the controller to get data*).then(function (response) {

 ...
  *make something with the response and set the state of the varable for the data table of the bootstrap table*

     self.setState({education: `dataFromResponse`}, 
                      () =>
                         {
                              *execute call back or code to set the state of readyToShow to true*  
                         }
                  )



});
```

it is important to make the state of ReadyToShow be updated after the state for education was set using the call back for the setState.

Comment: Hey Jose, 

I am having hard time understanding how having a condition inside my return statement would help? I have tried to display the bootstrap table only if the readyToShow is true, but it's not changing the view of the table.

Comment: I added some info to my answer